# Why does the allocated memory increase with the number of iterations of calling this lambda in sum()?

Tags: performance, lambda, julia

I'm just trying to experiment with Julia, so I wrote this code:

```
function f()
    i::Int = 0
    return () -> i += 1
end

@time (h = f(); sum(h() for _ in 1:1000000))
@time (h = f(); sum(h() for _ in 1:10000000))
```

When I ran it I obtain

```
  0.178856 seconds (3.07 M allocations: 49.691 MiB, 4.24% gc time, 33.87% compilation time)
500000500000
  1.128918 seconds (30.07 M allocations: 461.536 MiB, 4.79% gc time, 7.03% compilation time)
50000005000000
```

We see that it requires a lot of memory, that grows as the size of the range increases.  But I don't understand why, I'd expect it to require a constant amount of memory, basically the memory to store the lambda with its captured variable (and the variables required to compute the sum).
So the question is: why does the required memory grow with the size of the range?

(I know that I can obtain the same result simply with `sum(1:1000000)` or with other approaches, but this is not what I am interested in, here I'm just trying to understand this specific example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your function: boxing and binding in global scope. Here is an example how both can be resolved:

```
julia> function f()
           i = Ref(0)
           return () -> i[] += 1
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time let h = f()
           sum(h() for _ in 1:1000000)
       end
  0.027134 seconds (113.72 k allocations: 6.053 MiB, 98.97% compilation time)
500000500000

julia> @time let h = f()
           sum(h() for _ in 1:10000000)
       end
  0.024634 seconds (109.76 k allocations: 5.821 MiB, 96.81% compilation time)
50000005000000

julia> @time let h = f()
           sum(h() for _ in 1:100000000)
       end
  0.031428 seconds (109.76 k allocations: 5.826 MiB, 81.02% compilation time)
5000000050000000

julia> @time let h = f()
           sum(h() for _ in 1:1000000000)
       end
  0.088952 seconds (109.77 k allocations: 5.824 MiB, 8.99% gc time, 36.63% compilation time)
500000000500000000
```

Comment: Thank you!  But I'm not understanding why the autoboxing should be slower than your explicit boxing with Ref.  In addition, which binding in global scope was I doing that you aren't?

Comment: Finally, why doesn't the time get multiplied by 10 when you multiply by 10 the size of the range?  And why is @time (h = f(); sum(h() for _ in 1:1000000)) much slower than your version with let?

Comment: Ah, maybe I got it, the binding you are talking about is the one of h=f()

Comment: Because `Ref` is type stable. `let` makes `h` type stable. Time increases by `a+b*iterations` function. But the operation is so fast that `a` constant dominates the time as you can see in % of compilation time. `a` is cost to compile `h` (the allocations you see are mostly related to compilation allocations also).

Comment: Interestingly, if I define  `g() = let h = f()  sum(h() for _ in 1:1000000000) end` then the compiler is smart enough to obtain the result without looping through the range, like if I did `sum(1:1000000000)`, because it takes no time for the computation.  (If I prefix it with the @time macro, maybe optimizations are disabled and the computation takes some time, close to the time it takes with `@time sum(i for i in 1:1000000000)`.  I wonder, how is this optimisation achieved?

Comment: This is achieved by function inlining and constant propagation during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

because the closure over `i` is boxed, and accessing a boxed variable requires allocation, and thus it increase linearly as the number of time you access it.

The memory allocation is showing the total amount of memory allocated, not the peak memory.

and you can see the type instability:

```
julia> @code_warntype h()
MethodInstance for (::var"#3#4")()
  from (::var"#3#4")() @ Main REPL[1]:3
Arguments
  #self#::var"#3#4"
Locals
  i::Union{}
Body::Int64
1 ─ %1  = Core.getfield(#self#, :i)::Core.Box
│   %2  = Core.isdefined(%1, :contents)::Bool
└──       goto #3 if not %2
2 ─       goto #4
3 ─       Core.NewvarNode(:(i))
└──       i
4 ┄ %7  = Core.getfield(%1, :contents)::Any
│   %8  = Core.typeassert(%7, Main.Int)::Int64
│   %9  = (%8 + 1)::Int64
│   %10 = Core.getfield(#self#, :i)::Core.Box
│   %11 = Base.convert(Main.Int, %9)::Int64
│   %12 = Core.typeassert(%11, Main.Int)::Int64
│         Core.setfield!(%10, :contents, %12)
└──       return %9
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it type stable?